# how to get the html tag's ID name from html tag's value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to get html tag's ID name from content.
i have Following textboxes.
I want to find **id** which value is **"A2"**
Means I want to get result as **id=option2** because it's value = A2

```
<input type="text" name="option1" id="option1" value="A1">
<input type="text" name="option2" id="option2" value="A2">
<input type="text" name="option3" id="option3" value="A3">
<input type="text" name="option4" id="option4" value="A4">
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? You can't get the id without getting a reference to the element, but once you have a reference to the element what good is the id? Also, **do you want to use the original `value` attribute in the html source, or the _current_ value as edited by the user?**

Answer (score 2):

You can try with:

```
var id = $('input[value="A2"]').attr('id');
```

Output:

```
option2
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Attribute equals with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) in this context to accomplish your task.

Try,

```
console.log($('[type="text"][value="A2"]').attr('id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
var x= $('[type="text"][value="A2"]').get(0).id;

console.log(x);
```